# Perform FFT in Objective-C of MATLAB File

Tags: objective-c, matlab, fft, accelerate-framework, vdsp

For a current project I'm working on, I need to test the FFT I've implemented in Objective-C using the Accelerate Framework on a sin wave generated in MATLAB *before* I modify the FFT to read in real-time data. However, I'm a bit lost on how to load in the MATLAB file into my Xcode project and then test the file with my FFT...does anyone have any pointers on where to start?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the Matlab file format you are referring to is like (I'm assuming you mean a data file, not actual Matlab code). You could dump the data from Matlab to a [CSV](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html) or [XML](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/xmlwrite.html) file or whatever (the links are to documentation for functions provided by Matlab to do the dump), then read the data in using [CHCSVParser](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser) or [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Alternatively you can generate your [sine wave with the Accelerate framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vecLib/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vsinf) directly.